# How to transform with pivot in python pyspark

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data in excel as below

```
    col_1   col_2   col_3   00:00   01:00   02:00   03:00   04:00   06:00
0   cisc    am-01   RSR     11.00   99.72   99.75   99.75   99.83   99.82
1   cisc    am-01   CSRSR  12.00    99.99   99.99   99.99   99.99   99.99
2   cisc    am-01   DBRSR   13.00   99.97   99.95   99.95   99.95   99.98
3   cisc    am-01   DSRSR   14.99   98.45   98.71   98.79   98.83   98.72
4   cisc-2  am-02   RSR     12.00   12.34   10.00   11.22   22.34   99.74
5   cisc-2  am-02   CSRSR   12.00   23.99   99.99   99.99   99.99   99.56
6   cisc-2  am-02   DBRSR   18.00   34.99   99.95   99.95   99.95   99.98
7   cisc-2  am-02   DSRSR   98.00   67.99   98.71   98.79   98.83   98.72
```

and the required result as

```
    col_1   col_2   time    RSR     CSRSR   DBRSR   DSRSR
0   cisc    am-01   00:00   11.00   12.00   13.00   14.99
1   cisc    am-01   01:00   99.72   99.99   99.97   98.45
2   cisc    am-01   02:00   99.75   99.99   99.95   98.71
3   cisc    am-01   03:00   99.75   99.99   99.95   98.79
4   cisc    am-01   04:00   99.83   99.99   99.95   98.83
5   cisc    am-01   06:00   99.82   99.99   99.98   98.72
6   cisc-2  am-02   00:00   12.00   12.00   18.00   98.00
7   cisc-2  am-02   01:00   12.34   23.99   34.99   67.99
8   cisc-2  am-02   02:00   10.00   99.99   99.95   98.71
9   cisc-2  am-02   03:00   11.22   99.99   99.95   98.79
10  cisc-2  am-02   04:00   22.34   99.99   99.95   98.83
11  cisc-2  am-02   06:00   99.74   99.56   99.98   98.72
```

I try to split the data in two part first part for non transpose column as named as df 
and the other one for transpose df2

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.width', 100000)
df= pd.read_excel("./t2.xlsx")
df
df1 = df.iloc[:,[0,1]]
df1

df2 = df.iloc[:,[2,3,4,5,6,7]].set_index('col_3').T
df2
```

Is can we jointhese data frame? So that above result can be achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `stack()` and `unstack()`:

```
(df.set_index(['col_1','col_2','col_3'])
   .rename_axis(columns='time')
   .stack()
   .unstack('col_3')
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
col_3   col_1  col_2   time  CSRSR  DBRSR  DSRSR    RSR
0        cisc  am-01  00:00  12.00  13.00  14.99  11.00
1        cisc  am-01  01:00  99.99  99.97  98.45  99.72
2        cisc  am-01  02:00  99.99  99.95  98.71  99.75
3        cisc  am-01  03:00  99.99  99.95  98.79  99.75
4        cisc  am-01  04:00  99.99  99.95  98.83  99.83
5        cisc  am-01  06:00  99.99  99.98  98.72  99.82
6      cisc-2  am-02  00:00  12.00  18.00  98.00  12.00
7      cisc-2  am-02  01:00  23.99  34.99  67.99  12.34
8      cisc-2  am-02  02:00  99.99  99.95  98.71  10.00
9      cisc-2  am-02  03:00  99.99  99.95  98.79  11.22
10     cisc-2  am-02  04:00  99.99  99.95  98.83  22.34
11     cisc-2  am-02  06:00  99.56  99.98  98.72  99.74
```

Comment: .rename_axis(columns='time') //this line how its works ?

Comment: It gives the columns index a name (time) so it appears when you stack. Otherwise you would get `level_xxx` instead of `time`.